# Error while installing loadrunner standalone truclient12.56 version

Tags: performance-testing, truclient

I am getting an error while installing Truclient standalone 12.56 version

> This patch cannot be installed because the required HP software component is not installed. Please install the correct patch

I also tried to install the latest patch from HP site but it says that you *don't have permissions* for this.

Answer (score 0):

12.56 is a patch version that requires version 12.55 to be installed, as a prerequisite.
Note that version 12.56 is not available in the Community Edition.